# Cannot display mapview output after installing R 4.0.0

Tags: r, leaflet, rstudio, r-sf, r-mapview

After I installed the R 4.0.0, I cannot display the `mapview` output in the viewer of RStudio. It would be great if someone can give me some hints to solve this.

Here is an example code.

```
library(mapview)

mapview(breweries)
```

And here is a screenshot of my RStudio Viewer. There is no error message, but the viewer is just blank.

[image]

Here is my session information, and I am using RStudio Version `1.1.442`.

```
sessionInfo()
# R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
# Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
# Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
# 
# Matrix products: default
# 
# locale:
# [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
# [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    
# 
# attached base packages:  
# [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
# 
# other attached packages:
# [1] mapview_2.7.8
# 
# loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#  [1] Rcpp_1.0.4.6            RColorBrewer_1.1-2      compiler_4.0.0          base64enc_0.1-3         class_7.3-17           
#  [6] tools_4.0.0             digest_0.6.25           uuid_0.1-4              jsonlite_1.6.1          satellite_1.0.2        
# [11] lifecycle_0.2.0         lattice_0.20-41         viridisLite_0.3.0       png_0.1-7               rlang_0.4.6            
# [16] DBI_1.1.0               crosstalk_1.1.0.1       yaml_2.2.1              e1071_1.7-3             raster_3.1-5           
# [21] leaflet.providers_1.9.0 gdtools_0.2.2           htmlwidgets_1.5.1       systemfonts_0.2.3       stats4_4.0.0           
# [26] classInt_0.4-3          leaflet_2.0.3           grid_4.0.0              webshot_0.5.2           svglite_1.2.3          
# [31] sf_0.9-3                R6_2.4.1                sp_1.4-2                leafpop_0.0.5           magrittr_1.5           
# [36] scales_1.1.1            codetools_0.2-16        htmltools_0.4.0         units_0.6-6             colorspace_1.4-1       
# [41] brew_1.0-6              KernSmooth_2.23-17      munsell_0.5.0           leafem_0.1.1
```

Comment: can you view anything in the viewer, such as a ggplot() graph?

Comment: @PleaseHelp Yes, I can. `ggplot` and `base plot` both works. For example, if I do `plot(sf::st_geometry(breweries))`, this gives me a point map.

Comment: You might want to upgrade your RStudio version -- the most recent release is 1.3 and running your code displays the map fine for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be an issue of some combinations of `RStudio`, `R` and `leaflet` versions on Windows, see these GitHub issues:

- [Viewer Pane not working](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/6737) for RStudio
- [Leaflet maps don't appear in RStudio Viewer Pane (Windows + R v4.0)](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/678) for leaflet

Try to upgrade your RStudio, maybe it'll help (at least they say it's fixed for RStudio v1.3.957-1).